# UWP animations not playing simultaneously anymore

Tags: c#, .net, animation, uwp

I'm facing something quite strange in my UWP app since updating Windows 10 to 1909.
I have an XAML animation like the one below :

```
<Storyboard x:Key="showRightAnswer" x:Name="showRightAnswer">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="answerContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Transparent"/>
                <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="#32E662"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="answerContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="#EBEBEB"/>
                <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="#32E662"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="answer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="#787979"/>
                <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Storyboard is started in code behind when button is tapped. Button is defined as follow :

```
<Button x:Name="answerMainContainer" Tapped="AnswerMainContainer_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="52" Background="Transparent" Margin="0 0 0 20" Padding="0" MaxWidth="520" MinWidth="180" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform TranslateX="0"/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Border x:Name="answerContainer" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#EBEBEB" BorderThickness="2" Height="48" CornerRadius="24" MaxWidth="520" Padding="10" Margin="0" MinWidth="180">
            <TextBlock x:Name="answer" Text="{Binding Response}" Foreground="#787979" FontSize="16" FontFamily="{ThemeResource Regular}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        </Border>
</Button>
```

My problem is that the 3 color animations are not played sync and I can't figure out why. I can't see any problems coming from XAML.
So if anybody has a clue about this, I'll be more than happy.
Thanks in advance !

P.S: I'm running Windows 10 1909.

NuGet Packages installed are :

- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.2.9
- Win2D.uwp v1.24.0
- Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations v6.0.0
- Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls v6.0.0

Edit : 
[here is video example of rendering](https://streamable.com/qvaob)

Community test result
[image]

Comment: I tested above code and it works well, could share a video about your issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Link to video uploaded. I changed keytime from 2s to 0.2s because bad effect is more visible. Thanks for having a look

Comment: Sorry guys, I could not figure out  3 color animations are not played sync with your video.

Comment: Check out new video with 2s anim as in code shown into my answer.
Borderbrush is animated first. Then text. And at last background color of button without even the linear effect...

Comment: The issue only occurs in 1909? I tested in 1909 please check my screen shot in your question.

Comment: The only thing I did on my dev environnement was to update from 1903 to 1909 and really nothing else. I'm kinda really confused though because it seems you do not have the same result

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT did you try code as is ?
Because I tried something out of the blue, changing transparent to pure color everywhere. Looks like I got my anims back. But still can't figure out why...

Comment: May be the system issue, have you tested with other computer ?

Comment: @Maxime Your system issue, check your system resources, or run app manually after installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after checking on another system, I've the same exact problem occuring.
However, after changing transparent color to plain white color for both background start value and animation value, the problem seems to be solved.

So I guess either there is a problem with transparent color and standart color animations or both my systems confs are corrupted ;).

So for now, my solution is :
***Change transparent color to plain color***

Thanks for helping.